# Companies without filings or companyfacts on EDGAR

Tags: sec, edgar

I'm wondering why a handful of companies, mostly banks or financials, don't have filings or XBRL companyfacts data on EDGAR?

I'm new to EDGAR and was poking around. I noticed there are a handful of companies without data in XBRL companyfacts link `https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK**********.json`. These companies seem like they should have data. They are mostly banks.

Some examples:

SBNY - Signature Bank. Company has an $11B marketcap. [Yahoo finance shows data and financials.](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBNY?p=SBNY&.tsrc=fin-srch). Only [filings on EDGAR appear to be SC 13G](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=1288784) which I'm not overly familiar with past a google.

OZK - Bank OZK. $5B marketcap. [Yahoo has data.](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/OZK?p=OZK&.tsrc=fin-srch) [EDGAR only lists 13F-HR forms?](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=1569650)

FRC - First Republic Bank. $30B market cap. [Yahoo again has data.](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FRC?p=FRC&.tsrc=fin-srch) [EDGAR is a bit confusing on correct CIK, but the most obvious again holds SC 13G forms.](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FRC?p=FRC&.tsrc=fin-srch)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried asking these filers' investor relations?

Answer (score 1):

Are they all FDIC banks? Please see Edgar FAQ https://www.sec.gov/os/webmaster-faq#fdic-banks